# Should the ARG_TYPE for a CArray be const & or not

Tags: c++, templates, mfc

What's the difference between these 2 lines

```
CArray<MyClass, MyClass> MyArray

CArray<MyClass, const MyClass & > MyArray
```

Comment: I'm curious if even the second line would work...

Comment: Yes, it does, and I believe the second form is the default template type for the classes in VS2010 (ie: CArray<TYPE> expands to CArray<TYPE, const TYPE&>).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyClass is always copied to the array. But the first form copies it twice: the first time when its given as a parameter to the Add or SetAt function, the second time internally.
With the second form you avoid the first copy.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you need to have accessable copy constructor in `MyClass`, and `MyClass` will be passed by value (copied) in some members of `CArray`( in `CArray::Add` for instance).

Comment: I believe this still copies internally, with the way CArray allocates memory. You may avoid an extra copy, but you still need a publicly accessible copy operator.